# Protecting sensitive JSON data that is sent to mobile SDK (turning app into HTTPS)

Tags: django, api, heroku, https, ssl-certificate

I have an API endpoint which receives and sends sensitive data to a mobile SDK (that we created). The API lives in a Django Heroku app. I need to protect this information somehow, and I am a bit confused on where to start.

A friend of mine suggested provisioning HTTPS for my heroku app. After reading [SSL Endpoints for Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-endpoint#acquire-ssl-certificate), I couldn't be more confused. I read about buying a SSL certificate, yet their are so many different kinds, I don't know which one would fit my needs.

Mainly, my questions are:

1. What type of SSL certs do people get to protect APIs?
2. Would the mobile SDK require its own type of cert to interact safely with the web API?
3. Where can I buy/find a cert that fits my needs?
4. General question about HTTPS: Without HTTPS enabled, are logins able to be compromised on a heroku application with a custom domain?

Sorry if the questions are silly, I am new to SSL/HTTPS. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The main thing that HTTPSprotects you from is man-in-the-middle attacks: that is, someone sitting between the client and the server who reads your web traffic, either copying important data or modifying what you send. In that sense, it gives some protection from compromised logins - in that no-one will be able to sniff your password from the data - but doesn't protect you from anything else, eg getting passwords from cracking, or social engineering (phishing) attacks, etc.

In terms of what to buy, the links on that documentation give you all you need to know, so it's hard to know what you mean by your first or third questions. For the second one, certificates are for the server, not the client, so unless you're serving your mobile API on a completely different domain from the rest, you don't need a separate one.